# Squeezing spaces between columns in Unix shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I want the spaces to be removed between two columns.
After running a sql query from shell, I'm getting the output as below:

```
23554402243                       0584940772;2TZ0584940772001U;
23554402272                       0423721840;7TT0423721840001B;
23554402303                       0110770863;BBTU500248822001Q;
23554402305                       02311301;BTB02311301001J;
23554402563                       0550503408;PPTU004984208001O;
23554402605                       0457553223;Q0T0457553223001I;
23554367602                       0454542427;TB8U501674990001V;
23554378584                       0383071261;HTHU500374797001Y;
23554404965                       059792244;ST3059792244005C;
23554405503                       0571632586;QTO0571632586001D;
```

But the desired output should be like below:

```
23554400043     0117601738;22TU003719388001V;
23554402883     0823973229;TTT0823973229001C;
23554402950     024071080;MNT024071080001D;
23554405827     0415260614;TL20415260614001R;
23554405828     08119270800;TL2U003010407001G;
23554406553     011306895;VBT011306895001E;
23554406557     054121509;TL2054121509001M;
23554406563     065069209;TL2065069209005M;
23554409085     0803434328;QTO0803434328001B;
23553396219     062004063;G6T062004063001C;
```

Remember, there should be only one tabspace between two columns in the desired output.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to do using this `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1} 1' file
23554402243 0584940772;2TZ0584940772001U;
23554402272 0423721840;7TT0423721840001B;
23554402303 0110770863;BBTU500248822001Q;
23554402305 02311301;BTB02311301001J;
23554402563 0550503408;PPTU004984208001O;
23554402605 0457553223;Q0T0457553223001I;
23554367602 0454542427;TB8U501674990001V;
23554378584 0383071261;HTHU500374797001Y;
23554404965 059792244;ST3059792244005C;
23554405503 0571632586;QTO0571632586001D;
```

Alternatively this `tr` will also work:

```
tr -s ' ' < file | tr ' ' '\t'
```

or this `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak $'s/ \{1,\}/\t/g' file
```

Comment: yes, 'awk' and tr -s too working, does anyhow will it manipulate my file, as the output should be only tab spaced result between two columns.

Comment: Gnu awk can manipulate the file inplace otherwise use: `awk -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1} 1' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need to remove space between all the columns:

If you need tab spaced result between first two columns. Put `g` to apply changes between all the columns.

```
sed -r 's/\s+/\t/' inputfile
```

if `-r` is not available:

```
sed 's/\s\+/\t/'
```

or  If you need single space between every multi-space

`tr -s ' '`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but "-r" option is not working on my machine (HP-UX) getting error:  "sed: illegal option -- r"

Comment: ues `sed 's/\s\+/\t/'`

Comment: `echo  "23554402243                       0584940772;2TZ0584940772001U;" |sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/ /g'` will replace the concat of spaces with a single one

Answer (score 1):

what about the following `perl` *one-liner*?

```
perl -ne '/(.*?)\s+(.*)/; print "$1\t$2\n"' your_input_file
```